# How can I take varying chunks out of a Kotlin Sequence?

Tags: kotlin, sequence

If I have a Kotlin sequence, every invocation of `take(n)` restarts the sequence.

```
val items = generateSequence(0) {
    if (it > 9) null else it + 1
}

@Test fun `take doesn't remember position`() {
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1), items.take(2).toList())
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1, 2), items.take(3).toList())
}
```

Is there an easy way of write say, `another(n)` such that

```
@Test fun `another does remember position`() {
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1), items.another(2).toList())
    assertEquals(listOf(2, 3, 4), items.another(3).toList())
}
```

I suppose that I have to have something that isn't the `Sequence` to keep the state, so maybe what I'm actually asking for is a nice definition of `fun Iterator<T>.another(count: Int): List<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sequence` does not remember its position, but its `iterator` does remember:

```
val iterator : Iterator<Int> = items.iterator()
```

Now all you need is something like `take(n)` but for `Iterator<T>`:

```
public fun <T> Iterator<T>.another(n: Int): List<T> {
    require(n >= 0) { "Requested element count $n is less than zero." }
    if (n == 0) return emptyList()
    var count = 0
    val list = ArrayList<T>(n)
    for (item in this) {
        list.add(item)
        if (++count == n)
            break
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: 2 cracks at it eh? Which do you think is better?

Comment: This one answers the initial question, the other one is for people who will fix it in stdlib

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
    @Test
    fun `another does remember position`() {
        val items: Sequence<Int> = generateSequence(0) {
            if (it > 9) null else it + 1
        }

        val (first, rest) = items.another(2)
        assertEquals(listOf(0, 1), first.toList())
        assertEquals(listOf(2, 3, 4), rest.another(3).first.toList())
    }

    fun <T> Sequence<T>.another(n: Int): Pair<Sequence<T>, Sequence<T>> {
        return this.take(n) to this.drop(n)
    }
```

Comment: I like that this *is* referentially transparent

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last part of your question:

> I suppose that I have to have something that isn't the Sequence to keep the state, so maybe what I'm actually asking for is a nice definition of fun Iterator.another(count: Int): List

One such implementation would be:

```
fun <T> Iterator<T>.another(count: Int): List<T> {
    val collectingList = mutableListOf<T>()
    while (hasNext() && collectingList.size < count) {
        collectingList.add(next())
    }
    return collectingList.toList()
}
```

This passes your test if you use the iterator produced by the sequence:

```
@Test
fun `another does remember position`() {
    val items = generateSequence(0) {
        if (it > 9) null else it + 1
    }.iterator() //Use the iterator of this sequence.
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1), items.another(2))
    assertEquals(listOf(2, 3, 4), items.another(3))
}
```

To me what you've described is an iterator, since it's something that allows you to go over a collection or sequence etc. but also remember its last position.

NB the implementation above wasn't written to take into consideration what should happen for non-positive counts passed in, and if the count is larger than what's left to iterate over you'll be returned a list which has smaller size than n. I suppose you could consider this an exercise for yourself :-)

Comment: I've accepted @voddan's answer as his code was a little more efficient, but this is a fine answer

Answer (score 0):

`Sequence` does not remember its position, but its `iterator` does remember:

```
val iterator : Iterator<Int> = items.iterator()
```

Unfortunately there is no `take(n)` for an iterator, so to use the one from stdlib you need to wrap `iter` into an `Iterable`:

```
val iterable : Iterable<Int> = items.iterator().asIterable()

fun <T> Iterator<T>.asIterable() : Iterable<T> = object : Iterable<T> {
    private val iter = this@asIterable
    override fun iterator() = iter
}
```

That makes `itareble.take(n)` remember its position, but unfortunately there is a of-by-one error because the standard `.take(n)` asks for one element too many:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.take(n: Int): List<T> {
    require(n >= 0) { "Requested element count $n is less than zero." }
    if (n == 0) return emptyList()
    if (this is Collection<T>) {
        if (n >= size) return toList()
        if (n == 1) return listOf(first())
    }
    var count = 0
    val list = ArrayList<T>(n)
    for (item in this) {
        if (count++ == n)
            break
        list.add(item)
    }
    return list.optimizeReadOnlyList()
}
```

That can be fixed with a little tweak:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.take2(n: Int): List<T> {
    require(n >= 0) { "Requested element count $n is less than zero." }
    if (n == 0) return emptyList()
    if (this is Collection<T>) {
        if (n >= size) return toList()
        if (n == 1) return listOf(first())
    }
    var count = 0
    val list = ArrayList<T>(n)
    for (item in this) {


        list.add(item)
        //count++
        if (++count == n)
            break
    }
    return list
}
```

Now both of you tests pass:

```
@Test fun `take does not remember position`() {
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1), items.take2(2).toList())
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1, 2), items.take2(3).toList())
}

@Test fun `another does remember position`() {
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1), iter.take2(2).toList())
    assertEquals(listOf(2, 3, 4), iter.take2(3).toList())
}
```

Comment: 2 cracks at it eh? Which do you think is better?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function `generateStatefulSequence` which creates a sequence which keeps its state by using a second sequence's iterator to provide the values.

The iterator is captured in the closure of that function.

On each iteration the seed lambda (`{ i.nextOrNull() }`) of the returned sequence starts off with the next value provided by the iterator.

```
// helper
fun <T> Iterator<T>.nextOrNull() = if(hasNext()) { next() } else null

fun <T : Any> generateStatefulSequence(seed: T?, nextFunction: (T) -> T?): Sequence<T> {
    val i = generateSequence(seed) {
        nextFunction(it)
    }.iterator()

    return generateSequence(
        seedFunction = { i.nextOrNull() }, 
        nextFunction = { i.nextOrNull() }
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
val s = generateStatefulSequence(0) { if (it > 9) null else it + 1 }
println(s.take(2).toList())  // [0, 1]
println(s.take(3).toList())  // [2, 3, 4]
println(s.take(10).toList()) // [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

[Try it out](https://pl.kotl.in/a9sFPaEm2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice definition of `fun Iterator<T>.another(count: Int): List<T>` as requested:

```
fun <T> Iterator<T>.another(count: Int): List<T> =
        if (count > 0 && hasNext()) listOf(next()) + this.another(count - 1)
        else emptyList()
```

Answer (score 0):

As another workaround (similar to [the suggestion by Willi Mentzel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60122935/359949) above) would be to create a `asStateful()` extension method that converts any sequence into a one that will remember the position, by wrapping it into an `Iterable` that always yields the same iterator.

```kotlin
class StatefulIterable<out T>(wrapped: Sequence<T>): Iterable<T> {
    private val iterator = wrapped.iterator()
    override fun iterator() = iterator
}

fun <T> Sequence<T>.asStateful(): Sequence<T> = StatefulIterable(this).asSequence()
```

Then you can do:

```kotlin
val items = generateSequence(0) {
    if (it > 9) null else it + 1
}.asStateful()

@Test fun `stateful sequence does remember position`() {
    assertEquals(listOf(0, 1), items.take(2).toList())
    assertEquals(listOf(2, 3, 4), items.take(3).toList())
}
```

Try it here: https://pl.kotl.in/Yine8p6wn